# How to avoid duplication of tab in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hi I have set my website as a chrome extension.The problem is that number of times I click on the extension icon that many tabs are opened.I need that when I click on the extension icon I have to check if the tab has been already opened.If it is already opened then just display that tab.Otherwise create another tab.How can I do that?Please help me.I know that this is simple problem.Nut I am not able to figure it out.Please help me. 
Here is my background.js

```
  function getGmailUrl() {
    return "http://calpinemate.com/";
    }
     function isGmailUrl(url) {

      return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;
         }
       chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(undefined, function(tabs) {
for (var i = 0, tab; tab = tabs[i]; i++) {
  if (tab.url && isGmailUrl(tab.url)) {
    console.log('Found Gmail tab: ' + tab.url + '. ' +
                'Focusing and refreshing count...');
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {selected: true});          
    return;
  }
  }
console.log('Could not find Gmail tab. Creating one...');
chrome.tabs.create({url: getGmailUrl()});
  });

 });
```

I am not able to figure out what is the problem.Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the conditions in your for-loop are messed up, so it is not looping over all tabs.
BTW, **[chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-getAllInWindow)** is deprecated. Use **[chrome.tabs.query](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query)** instead (see below).

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        url: "http://calpinemate.com/*",
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        if (tabs.length > 0) {
            var tab = tabs[0];
            console.log("Found (at least one) Gmail tab: " + tab.url);
            console.log("Focusing and refreshing count...");
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
        } else {
            console.log("Could not find Gmail tab. Creating one...");
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: getGmailUrl() });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hi..thank you so much for the reply.I will try it and let you know.